# Groovy JsonSlurper date deserialization

Tags: json, groovy

Is there a decent way to deserialize a date coming out of JSON that was serialized by JsonBuilder?  JsonBuilder serializes a java.util.Date like this:

```
{"hour":"2013-01-07T04:00:00+0000"}
```

JsonSlurper sucks this in and sees it as a string.  Do I really have to do a simple date format on this?  I really would just want a java.util.Date automatically out of JsonSluper parseText.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe slightly less verbose:

```
Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ", json.hour)
```

Answer (score 2):

JsonSlurper can be configured with different types of parsers base on the needs.

To parse a date string into Date object automatically, you may use the
**JsonParserType.INDEX_OVERLAY** parser (care must taken if parsed maps are put into a long term cache) -- https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html

```
def json = groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(["date":new Date()])
println json //  {"date":"2020-11-06T09:27:22+0000"}

def map = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper()
    .setType(groovy.json.JsonParserType.INDEX_OVERLAY)
    .parseText(json)

assert map.date instanceof Date
```

Answer (score 0):

Can do this after getting it from string out of JsonSlurper parseText

```
def jutilDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ").parse(dateStr);
```

Hoping for better way